# Python websocket-client module and processor load

Tags: python, websocket

I ran my python code on the notebook i3 (2nd generation two physical core) and PC i7-8700 (6 physical core). Simple script that connect to message stream server, run_forever and on_message.
But I received the same processor load 15-16% on all cores(not more not less, even when server no send message in stream)....(ubuntu top)...

Why same result on processors with different power...  How to decrease processor load on  i7-8700....

Today I try to replace websocket-client module to async websockets, but in the period when server send message with high freq, some code in `on_message` didn't pass to the end and miss 50 or 75%..

Comment: even if it doesn't send message it still have to run loop which runs all code and check if there is next request. Normally you could use some `sleep` to use less CPU but I don't know how to do it in server which runs many hidden code. Eventually you can use Linux/Ubuntu program to block access to CPU - [cpulimit](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cpulimit.1.html) - but if you will run on server then you can't decide how to start script and you can't use `cpulimit`

Comment: Why on the PC with benchmark 13000 and notebook with benchmark 2700 is the same load 15%? If I try to use sleep I miss some message...